# Inappropriate to list my client's net worth?

Tags: resume, linkedin

I've worked as a freelance web developer and have had a client with a net worth well into 7 figures.

I feel proud of this achievement and want people to know my skills are scalable, but I could see how *some* may perceive it as bragging or inappropriate.

**Would it be inappropriate to state on LinkedIn, or a CV, something like:**

*During my time as a freelancer, I've managed projects for multi-million pound companies*

**If not, how could I word it to make it appropriate yet retaining it's value as an achievement?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Vietnhi Notes (this is, of course, becoming something of a go-to opening phrase for me), the  *name* isn't as important as the *work*.

As you note, you "want people to know my skills are scalable". If this work does show that, then, yes, of course mention it. However, just *because* the client is large doesn't itself mean anything - large companies will have need of window washers just as much as small companies, the size differential between companies does not translate to one window washer being "better".

To that end, your phrase "During my time as a freelancer, I've managed projects for multi-million pound companies" *is* bad, in the sense that it doesn't express that you've done anything of note, but *does* read like bragging.

A better way would be:

~~~~~

**Prior Experience**

*Some multi-million-pound-company* (date started-finished): managed the XYZ project, which successfully launched on time and on budget. The project contributed to 15% cost reduction in the ABC department, and 10% improved sales of widgets.

*Some smaller company* (date started-finished) : whatever you did here

~~~~

and so on.

But this doesn't make sense to me - presumably you know how to write a CV, and linkedIn certainly leads you to input the name of the company, the date range, and what you did there.

Are you instead asking if, in that little intro space linkedIn provides, that you write "During my time as a freelancer, I've managed projects for multi-million pound companies?" It is still a waste of space as it sounds fluffy and braggy. A better way would be

"Specialist  whatever-you-do freelance consultant. I've successfully delivered whatever-projects-you-do adjectives-on-time-on-budget-maybe for companies in the what-domain-is-this? ranging in size from small-company to -this-large-company"

Now it sounds like you do whatever it is you do well, and the large company is there to stress that you can work in all sorts of different environments. Much less braggy!

Answer (score 2):

Not inappropriate in terms of good taste. Inappropriate perhaps in terms of relevance. Hey, if I managed a $10K project for a big company and the same $10K project for a three-person outfit including their dog, what's the difference? :) And what's the differential achievement that's worth noting?

Comment: That's different as you're talking about the cost of the project, I'm talking about the net worth of the company who's entrusted me to manage their web presence. That's the achievement.

Comment: That's not an achievement to me. You most likely disagree, so we'll let others weigh in on that.

Comment: I would argue that building Apple's website for free is more impressive than building your uncle's used car dealerships website for a sizeable payment, although I can see your point

Comment: Depends what the specs are for Apple's website as opposed to your uncle's. I'd be more impressed if you built your uncle's website using the Ionic Angular mobile framework then if you did a couple of static pages for Apple's website :) At the end of the day, companies hire you based on what you can do for them.

Comment: i uh, i just stole your advice and wrote more around it.

Comment: @bharal I see that you are devastated over what you have done - if you feel no shame at all about  taking something and doing a better job of it than I did, then you are my kind of guy :)

Comment: It's like having been involved with sales to C-Level executives, not so much the thin you're selling or the sophistication of the technology you developed, but the demonstrated ability to work with large contracts.

Comment: If you are a marketing company and you can get a Fortune 500 company to buy your recommendation for a new logo that is nothing but a white square, you've accomplished something very valuable. You understand this market segment and know how to speak their language.

Answer (score 2):

As Dizzy Dean said, "It's not bragging if you've done it." Everyone asks for references and want to know you work history so why not? Large clients take a lot of hand-holding. They have the resources to be very demanding on their business partners.

Many people perceive large companies as knowing what they're doing (that's how they got so big) and if you're good enough for them, you're good enough for smaller clients who aspire to be big one day.